# Rails sort Upper and Lower case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, sorting

I have a problem with the sort that rails is doing it appears that Upper case are group together and then lower case are group together. And I Agree that data in the database should be the same but something you cant help user input.

my search controller

```
def accounts
    @accounts ||= Account.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 100, :page => params[:page])
  end
  helper_method :accounts

  def account
    @account ||= params[:id] ? Account.find(params[:id]) : Account.new(params[:account])
  end
  helper_method :account

  def sort_column
    Account.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

in my model i have

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

Now this works perfectly but it shows 
A
B
C
a
b
c

And it should be 
A
a
B
b
C
c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way that I like to do it is like

```
result = Users.find(:all, :order => "LOWER(#{params[:sort]} #{params[:direction]})")
```

Answer (score 2):

the call to order just creates a "ORDER BY" call to your database. have a look at your logs to verify this. if you want a different order, than you need to tweak the way that your database orders the results!

Answer (score 1):

if you use the

> where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%")

instead on the

> LIKE